# Running shell script in cron

Tags: script, cron

I am using ubuntu in rapsberry pi 2. I want my script to be ran after I login because it is a GUI program. I have tried to edit /etc/profile and it runs the program before enter the desktop so it cause some of the GUI failed to run. Therefore, I tried to use crontab and it works but I faced some problems.

Here is the line I appended into crontab.

> @reboot sh /home/ubuntu/testing.sh >/home/ubuntu/logs/cronlog 2>&1

Here is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash

source /home/ubuntu/ros_package/devel/setup.bash
roslaunch uvc_camera camera_node.launch &

source /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
rosrun hybrid_tracking ir_track
```

Here is my output log.

> /home/ubuntu/testing.sh: 3: /home/ubuntu/testing.sh: source: not found
>
> /home/ubuntu/testing.sh: 20: /home/ubuntu/testing.sh: source: not found
>
> /home/ubuntu/testing.sh: 4: /home/ubuntu/testing.sh:
>
> /home/ubuntu/testing.sh: 21: /home/ubuntu/testing.sh: rosrun: not found
> roslaunch: not found

I have tested my script and it is running in terminal but why there are errors when I run it in cron?

Comment: `cron` executes the scripts using `/bin/sh`, so the command `source` is unknown. Use a simple `.` ( a dot) to include scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be due to access right problems.

Your crontab entry must be run with correct user to have access to the home folder of user `ubuntu`. So you either add the entry as user `ubuntu` doing running `crontab`, as root running `crontab -u ubuntu -e`, or you can put your entry into a file in `/etc/cron.d` with an entry formatted as a normal cronjob, but with an extra user field:

```
#<timing>   <user> <command>
11 * * * *  ubuntu /home/ubuntu/testing.sh
```

Furthermore make shure that your commands are accessible, probably use absolute paths.

Comment: I have tested `sudo crontab -u ubuntu -e` but the result still the same. How to put entry in `/etc/cron.d`?

Comment: You should add a file without extension into that directory. Please refer to `man cron(8)` for more information.

Comment: What's much more important, however, is to use absolute pahts to `roslaunch` and what you else call. Find the absolute path to hem by using `type`, e.g. `type roslaunch`.

Comment: Now it works. It ran but it failed to open the display.

Comment: I guess you want to start a ros node on boot, maybe using [ros-system-daemon-groovy](https://github.com/TurtleBot-Mfg/ros-system-daemon-groovy)  is a way to do it.

Comment: Or you can try [clearpathrobotics/robot_upstart](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/robot_upstart).

Answer (score 1):

I actually found out the answer.

> sudo nano /etc/cron.d/anacron

Append this line at the bottom.

> @reboot user_name export DISPLAY=:0 && /bin/bash /home/user/testing.sh >/home/user/logs/cronlog 2>&1

My script.

```
sleep 10
lxterminal -e /home/user/xxx.sh
```

It can straight away open the script but I use one script to run another script because I need the terminal. Straight away open terminal will face error "cannot open display" in my case. Seem like it haven get ready so I delay 10 seconds and run it.